# Design issues with UITableView cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

Have some design issues with my Table View. Below is an image of what my end-result should look like (Sorry, new user so can't display images or more than two hyperlinks).

http://casperslynge.dk/2.png

And below is what it looks like at the moment:

http://casperslynge.dk/iphone1.png

I can't make my view in my xib file (attached to a TableViewCell) fill the entire window (width or height). If I set the width to 320 it looks like the picture above. It starts at the beginning of the cell (top left side). How can I change this?

In the next UITableView which is activated when pressing a cell, there is no problem (see picture below), but there isn't any change in code in the two Table View Controllers.

(http://casperslynge.dk/iphone2.png)

Finally I have a desire to insert the cells from the "Abonnementer" picture into my "Selskaber" TableView, like a drop down menu (see last picture). Is this possible?

(http://casperslynge.dk/3.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is of the grouped style then this may produce the results in your second image,  though it's hard to tell because it's all very customised.

I'm assuming your xib for the cell has a view on it that you wish to fill the whole frame of the cell? This is possible by setting the origin and frame settings in interface builder.

Inserting a drop down menu in a table view isn't really conventional design but you can reconfigure a cell to grow if you select a certain control, then add subviews to it - this is not a straightforward process and should probably be asked as a separate question.

You set the grouped / plain style here. This table is "grouped" style.

[image: Table view style]

Looking at your screenshot I am sure this is what you have. You can see the rounded corners in the background.

If you do stick with the grouped style, you can clip to the rounded corners by choosing the cell in interface builder, and then selecting "Clip to bounds"

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Group Style? Can I change this?

Yeah, in my xib file I have a TableViewCell with a view inside it. And in the view I have all my labels. But I have done exactly the same with the TableView in the third image. I just tried changing the origin and frame settings. They are exactly the same in the two TableViews. The origin is set to the center, width 320.

Okay, will probably just keep it the way it is now then.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the setting in interface builder. Because if I can't get the view to fill the entire window I would prefer, as you mention, to have rounded corners at top and bottom.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to chat :/ But appreciate the help. Which version of interface builder/xcode do you have? Because I don't have the same "style" option.

Comment: Should I use a Table View inside my xib file? Right now I only have a Table View Cell with a view inside it. Should I put the Table View Cell inside a Table View object?

Comment: Okay I found the "Style" setting. It is inside the Table View object.

Comment: The tableview will be in a separate nib, or you are adding one in code.

Comment: Well I have my Controller class which is a UITableViewController.. It is inside that, that I create my UITableViewCell which loads the nib file.