# UITableViewController cell design issue

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with an attached xib file. Inside the xib file i have a TableViewCell object with a view inside it along with labels on the view. Below is an image of what my result should be:

[pic1 http://casperslynge.dk/2.png](http://casperslynge.dk/2.png)

And below is how my tableview is looking atm.

[pic2 http://casperslynge.dk/iphone1.png](http://casperslynge.dk/iphone1.png)

My issue is that I can't get the table view cell to fill the entire window. Have tried everything inside the interface builder. Nothing to do with the origin or the width/height. Below is how I instantiate my cell with the xib file and fill my labels with data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString * CompanyListCellIdentifier =
@"CompanyList";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CompanyListCellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CompanySubscriptionView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

}
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
CompanyModel *company = [list objectAtIndex:row];

name.text = company.name;
network.text = company.networks;
NSString* subscriptionCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", company.subscriptions.count];
subscriptionCount.text = subscriptionCountString;
fromPrice.text = company.fromPrice;
NSString* trustScoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", company.trustScore];
trustScore.text = trustScoreString;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

}

The weird thing is that in the next view when one of the cell's are pressed, I have no issue making the view fill the entire width and height, and it is created in exactly the same way (see picture below). Is it something in the xib file that I am doing wrong or in the code?

[pic3 http://casperslynge.dk/iphone2.png](http://casperslynge.dk/iphone2.png)

Can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design issues with UITableView cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476330/design-issues-with-uitableview-cells). You should go back and edit your original question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry. Will just delete the other one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from screenshots you are trying to use table view with grouped style while you definitely need a plain one (at least for first view).

Comment: Exactly, but the thing is I haven't set the UITableViewController to be grouped anywhere. Inside my xib file I only have my TableViewCell object with a view, and there is no style setting for a TableViewCell that allows you to select group or plain. Is it possible to change the setting from code?

Comment: Take a better look at Interface Builder as it do have UITableView style property

Comment: Figured out the problem. It was inside my code that I initiated it with UITableViewStyleGrouped. Thanks for the help.